# Django: how to distinguish AJAX POST request?

Tags: django, jquery

I have a form that gets submitted using jQuery's .post().

In the corresponding view function, is there a way that I can use to determine that the requested received is AJAX?

I have seen code snippet dated back to 2006, which uses

```
request.GET.has_key('xhr')
```

But I don't see anything in my request.GET. I am guessing the above might be obsolete.

Please advise what I can do to achieve my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
request.is_ajax()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I remembered seeing this function before but when I needed it I couldn't find it. Thanks again.